# Why could a service account fail to reference its own default schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure which runs happily as a Windows user but which fails when invoked by a service account.  I doubt it being a service account is relevant, rather, the permissions of the 2 accounts are different in a way I cannot fathom.

The Windows user derives its permissions from an AD group.  This too may, or may not, be relevant.

The service account has 'dbo' as its default schema.  The AD group has no default schema.

The error I see when invoking from the service account is

```
The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it
```

The stored procedure references at least 2 dbo.Tables, one of which has just been created by the same user.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

---

I found a solution without really getting to grips with the underlying problem; by making the service account a member of db_owner the service now works.  The AD Group does not have this membership so I am in the dark as to what is happening.  I would still like to find an explanation because db_owner is too permissive for my needs.

Comment: I would suggest that, as the error says, the user does not have permission. Either due to a lack of any `GRANT` permissions or there is an explicit `DENY` (which would override any `GRANT` permissions).

Comment: I agree.  I cannot for the life of me see what it is, though.

Comment: In SSMS > ServerName > Security > Logins the service account's Windows Login will have a default database setting - is it the correct database? If the service's connection string specifies a Database or Initial Catalog setting - is it the correct database?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - yes it correct, although the default is only half of the story because the service is moving data from tables in one db to another.